# useState updating state child array object not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this state in my React component-->

```
const [employeeState, setEmployee] = useState({
        "empName": null,
        "Age": null,
        "depts": [], //depts is an array of objects
        "groups": [] //group is an array of objects
});
```

I have a separate state for depts and groups like follows -->

```
const depts = {
        "name": "some name",
        "code": "s123",
}
const [deptState, setDeptState] = useState([
        { ...depts},
]);
```

same is for groups too....

Now when I am trying to set the employee state on some btn click like below it's not updating and keeping `depts` and `groups` property as it is empty -->

```
const deptsLst = [...deptState];
const groupsLst = [...groupstate];
console.log(depsLst); // this will print the results as expected
console.log(groupsLst); // this will print the results as expected
setEmployee({
      ...employeeState,
      ['depts']: deptsLst ,
      ['groups']: groupsLst ,
})
 console.log(employeeState);// this will show depts and groups as empty only
```

I am new to this **spread variable** copying concept. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: " it's not updating and keeping depts and groups " how do you know?

Comment: What is are you trying to achieve with `[{ ...depts},]`? As this is the same as `[depts]`

Comment: @JonasWilms I am checking in console.log

Comment: @user2340824 I just read it somewhere that that's how u do it if you want to make a copy or clone of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state that "I am new to this spread variable copying concept"...not only are you new to the spread operation but your code demonstrates that you do not have a basic understanding of it I think. You are using spread operators on top of spread operators on top of computed property names, all for no reason.

You are also using React state to manage the employee object and then using React state to manage Array properties on the employee object. If you are already performing state management on the employee object, why maintain state of individual properties?

Ok a couple breakdowns of your code:

```
const depts = {
        "name": "some name",
        "code": "s123",
}
const [deptState, setDeptState] = useState([
        { ...depts},
]);
```

Above you clone an object for no reason.

With React state management you only need to clone objects to trigger a render event. A clone creates a new object with a new reference in memory, will "react" to object reference changes and trigger a state change event. React is not capable of watching every property of a complex object, especially array elements to see if a value has changed.

The below code will suffice, you are initializing state, you do not need to clone:

```
const [deptState, setDeptState] = useState([{
        "name": "some name",
        "code": "s123",
}]);
```

Next this code:

```
setEmployee({
      ...employeeState,
      ['depts']: deptsLst ,
      ['groups']: groupsLst ,
})
```

Here you are attempting to use the spread operator to clone the "employeeState" object and update new values for the `depts` property key and `groups` property key. You use "Computed Property Names' for property keys for no reason.

This is sufficient:

```
setEmployee({
      ...employeeState,
      depts: deptsLst ,
      groups: groupsLst
})
```

You also create unnecessary state:

```
const [deptState, setDeptState] = //..rest of code omitted
```

Here you do not realize React state changes happen async:

```
setEmployee({
      ...employeeState,
      ['depts']: deptsLst ,
      ['groups']: groupsLst ,
})
console.log(employeeState);
```

The above code actually has changed the employeeState, just not be the time of your `console.log(employeeState)`;

Ok, so to start I have [created a CodePen](https://codepen.io/sweetog/pen/gOOKvOq) for you to understand how state changes.

When you want to change state for this employee object of yours you simply need to change the object property values or add new property values and then clone the employee object to change its reference and than call setState with the clone, consider this object state:

```
const [employee, setEmployee] = React.useState({
    "empName": 'Jane Doe',
    "Age": 33,
    "depts": [
        {
            "name": "some name",
            "code": "s123",
        }
    ]
});
```

Here I am adding a department to the employee, note I only clone the employee object to trigger React to detect the overall object reference change, React does not know I changed property `depts` array but the new state does have my new value I pushed on the department array:

```
function exampleUpdatingEmployee() {
    employee.depts.push({
        "name": "some new dept",
        "code": "876",
    });
    setEmployee({ ...employee });
}
```

Comment: yah you are right Brian I am just learning React directly by doing a small demo project. This answer saved me from spending days of understanding how setting a state works in React.

Comment: Regarding your last example: Components that receive `employee.depts` may not update since it's reference did not change.

Comment: @FelixKling but the parent employee object has been cloned so React will update the entire object with the clone yes?

Comment: @FelixKling yes you are right I see what you are saying now, I will update my answer to reflect this, thank you

Comment: @VishalNair I am very glad I was helpful, that was my intent, to clear up many issues at once for you, quickly. I have added more examples to my CodePen FYI https://codepen.io/sweetog/pen/gOOKvOq

Comment: @FelixKling I have updated my CodePen to clearly test my last scenario, ReactJS 16.10 is indeed updating child components without changing the departments array reference, just changing the parent employee reference is sufficient https://codepen.io/sweetog/pen/gOOKvOq

Comment: Yes, it works if you are not doing anything too fancy, but lets say a component uses `const length = useMemo(() => depts.length, [depts])` or even `React.memo`, then the result/output will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
setEmployee({
  ...employeeState,
  depts: deptsLst,
  groups: groupsLst
})
```

to update your employeeState. You probably won't see the update with the `console.log` you have right after that since it will execute before the state updates. You can verify that the `employeeState` updated by using a `useEffect` function like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(employeeState)
  }, [employeeState])
```

The spread operator is the ES6 way of copying arrays without passing a reference to your copy so you can modify one array without those changes showing up in the other array. You can read into that more here: [Reference And Copying Objects & Arrays](https://dev.to/simo_benhida/reference-and-copying-objetcs--arrays-in-javascript-2h23).

Answer (score 0):

if depts and group are arrays of objects, you should use spread operator in this way to copy values:

```
setEmployee({
      ...employeeState,
      depts: [...deptState],
      groups: [...groupstate]
});
```

so if:

```
const employeeState = {status: 'hungry'};
const deptState = ['one', 'two'];
const groupstate = ['y', 'k', 'o'];
```

then the first code, after spread, is like:

```
setEmployee({
   status: 'hungry',
   depts: ['one', 'two'],
   groups: ['y', 'k', 'o']
});
```